# Python get file's info

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, metadata, file-handling

I have some files in my downloads folder : 'C:\EXP_Downloads\' (Windows 10 Home 64b)

My requirement is : “get the files downloaded today.”

For now I made like this, to firstly read the folder and get basic info:

```
import os
import time


def list_target_files(target_folder):
    target_files = get_required_files(target_folder)
    for this_file_info in target_files:
        print(this_file_info)


def get_required_files(dir_in):
    all_files = os.listdir(dir_in)
    output = []
    for this_file_info in all_files:
        file_path = dir_in+this_file_info
        rec_out = {this_file_info, mod_date(file_path)}
        output.append(rec_out)
    return output


def mod_date(name_arq):
    return time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d", time.localtime(os.path.getctime(name_arq)))


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    list_target_files(r'C:\\EXP_Downloads\\')
```

Concerning the results obtained, here’s The question:

- Why some records contain {name, date} and others contain {date,name} ?

> ```
> {'2020/05/01', 'another_document.odt'}
>
> {'2020/05/01', 'file_output(1).txt'}
>
> {'file_output.txt', '2020/04/30'}
>
> {'2020/05/02', 'HelloWorld.class'}
>
> {'Megaman.jpg', '2020/05/02'}
>
> {'2020/05/01', 'one_document.odt'}
>
> {'2020/05/01', 'one_pdf.pdf'}
>
> {'putty-64bit-0.73-installer.msi', '2020/04/30'}
>
> {'2020/05/01', 'Spreadsheet1.ods'}
> ```

Comment: `rec_out = {this_file_info, mod_date(file_path)}` this is a set , sets are unordered, soyou cannot be sure ordering in them. Do you mean to use a list here? ``rec_out = [this_file_info, mod_date(file_path)]` or a tuple?

Comment: You nailed this. Set is not suitable for this use. I'll try tuples. Thanks!